# MySQL db in AWS didn't autoscale the way the firm expected, trying to understand why

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, autoscaling

**Outline of environment**: Data collection service that gets anywhere from 10 Million to 17 Million rows of data a day stored in database.

**Problem**: Our database was overloaded and 'enable auto scaling' was configured on. Auto scale never happened and our db failed to collect data due to full-storage so we had an outage.

Available storage steadily decline
[image: Screen shot of the data base storage decline]

The mouse is hovering exactly when the outage occurred
[image: Same screen shot with the hover pointing to the exact outage time]

Here is the config for the db in question
[image: Screen shot of Auto scale turned on]

**Things Tried Already**: I looked at the docs and trying to figure out why this outage occurred.

*Potential Explanation 1*:

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html#USER_PIOPS.Autoscaling):

> Autoscaling doesn't occur if the maximum storage threshold would be
> equaled or exceeded by the storage increment.

This might be the reason why it didn't scale. When the outage occurred, our storage flatlines at 1,000 GiB without collecting more data, is that the expected outcome with these configurations?

*Potential Explanation 2*:

Also, from the docs:

> Autoscaling can't completely prevent storage-full situations for large
> data loads. This is because further storage modifications can't be
> made for either six (6) hours or until storage optimization has
> completed on the instance, whichever is longer.

I noticed this RDS status [image: this]
The screen shot was taken at Monday 6:54 pm EST and outage occurred at Wednesday 10:48 pm EST so > 6 hours later. And the RDS status went back to Available in-between the storage optimization status and having an outage. So I don't think it's this one.

**My Conclusion**: I think autoscaling didn't work because of our Maximum Storage Threshold was only set to 1000.

**Avoiding this problem in the future**: If we would have set Maximum Storage Threshold to 6,500 would the chart look like this?

[image: would this be the expect outcome?]

We still would have had an outage but the autoscale would have bought us more time (where the blue circle is where the outage would have occurred)? If I'm incorrect with that last statement, then I'm not sure how to use autoscale correctly.

Am I on the right track, or am I way off base here? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming. What are your thoughts on the last graph, am I understanding the process correctly? If I changed the threshold to ~60,000, the free space graph might have looked like that?

Comment: How much storage space does it say it currently has? Also you should be able to look at the RDS event log to see when scaling events happened, which would be an important data point.

Comment: 321 GiB. If my max threshold is 1,000, it should have been able to scale. The writer writes 200x a second, could that have been the issue?

Comment: I suggest switching to AWS Aurora MySQL which would not have this problem.

Comment: "Free storage" -- Can you show, instead, "Disk space used"?

Answer (score 0):

How does the **"auto-scaling"** work?  MySQL is designed to work in any amount of RAM, given that it is correctly configured.  That is, MySQL won't "run out of RAM", instead it will get slower.

In the case of I/O, tell us how the "17 Million rows of data per day" are `INSERTed`.  **IOPS** is very unlikely to catch that.  Instead, the inserts are likely to get delayed longer and longer.

For both of these, it *may* be possible to rewrite how the ingestion can scale well beyond 17M, even without scaling up.  Please provide details on where the data comes from, how it is collected, how it is (or is not) batched, and what the **`INSERT`** statement(s) look like.  Include in the discussion whether there are multiple threads doing the processing.

If it is not on, please turn on the **slowlog** with a low value for `long_query_time`.  That output may help us locate the main query to work on optimizing.

Do you have **other apps** running on the same server?  The sawtooth nature looks a bit like garbage collection in Java (which MySQL does not use).

If you are running apps on the same machine as MySQL, you should seriously consider splitting them apart.

What does **"storage-full situations"** mean?  Is it referring to the amount of stuff stored on disk?  If so, then let's discuss the tables you have.  Some techniques we can discuss:

- Smaller datatypes
- Purging 'old' data (perhaps with `PARTITIONing` by date)
- Normalization

There is not a lot that AWS can do to purge the disk without seriously destroying your data.  Perhaps it as at the limit, and the "quick fix" is to bump the instance up to the next larger *disk*.  (Meanwhile, we can do the other suggestions here -- so you can drop back to this size of **disk** to again save money.)

Comment: It's RDS, which is a managed service. You can't run other things on the server.